# How to add a color stripe to every last row of a student attendance sheet using Google App Scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

As part of a student attendance system, I would like to add a color stripe to every last row of a class for attendance using App Scripts. My columns of Google Sheets are: (i) Date, (ii) Email, (iii) Latitude, (iv) Longitude, and (v) Subject-code. Tried many ways but did not find the solution.

```
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssID = sss.getId();
  var sheetName = sss.getName(); 
  var sheet = sss.getSheetByName("TempDataSet");
  var sheet1 = sss.insertSheet('TempDataSet_temp');
  sheet.getDataRange().copyTo(sheet1.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  sheet.getDataRange().copyTo(sheet1.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);

  
  var shID = sheet1.getSheetId().toString();
  sheet1.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() -1, sheet.getLastColumn()).sort({column: 1, ascending: false}); 
  var columns_delete = [7,2]; //[7,5,4,2];
  columns_delete.forEach(col=>sheet1.deleteColumn(col));

  //const sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //const sheet = sss.getSheetByName("TempDataSet");
  
  const subs = sheet.getRange('F2:F'+sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const usubs = subs.filter((value, index, self)=>self.indexOf(value) === index);
  const dts = sheet.getRange('A2:A'+sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().flat();
  const udts = dts.filter((value, index, self)=>self.indexOf(value) === index);
  
  if(usubs.length>1){
    subs.forEach((s,i)=>{
    if(i>1){
      if(subs[i]!=subs[i-1]){
        sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,5).setBackground('yellow');
      }}});
  }
  else if (udts.length>1){
    dts.forEach((d,i)=>{
    if(i>1){
      if(dts[i]!=dts[i-1]){
        sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,5).setBackground('yellow');
      }}});
  }
 
  var from = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var subject = 'Batch Attendance Record for Your Reference';
  var body = 'Dear Student,'+ '\n\n' + 'Greetings! Please find the batch attendance record attached. Stay safe and blessed.' + '\n\n' + 'Thank you.';
  
  var requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};  
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ ssID + "/export?format=xlsx&id="+ssID+"&gid="+shID;

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);  
  var contents = result.getContent();
  sss.deleteSheet(sss.getSheetByName('TempDataSet_temp'));   
  
  var sheet2 = sss.getSheetByName('StudentList');  
  var data = sheet2.getLastRow();
  var students = [];
  var students = sheet2.getRange(2, 6, data).getValues(); 
  //MailApp.sendEmail(students.toString(), subject ,body, {attachments:[{fileName:sheetName+".xlsx", content:contents, mimeType:"MICROSOFT_EXCEL"}]});
    
  for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++){ // you are looping through rows and selecting the 1st and only column index
    if (students[i][0] !== ''){           
      MailApp.sendEmail(students[i][0].toString(), subject ,body, {attachments:[{fileName:sheetName+".xlsx", content:contents, mimeType:"MICROSOFT_EXCEL"}]}); 
      //MailApp.sendEmail(students[i][0].toString(), subject ,body, {from: from, attachments:[{fileName:"YourAttendaceRecord.xlsx", content:contents, mimeType:"MICROSOFT_EXCEL"}]});
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

Based on your question, I understand the following steps:

1. Check if you have **at least two unique subjects** in column **E**. One way to do that is to find the unique list of subjects. If the length of that list is `2` or more it means that you have different subjects. In that case, the **first** block of the `if` statement evaluates to `true` and you add a yellow line in the row before the subject is changed.
2. If you have **only one subject**, namely the length of the unique list of subjects is `1` the first block of the `if` statement will evaluate to `false`. In that case, the script will check whether column **A** has `2` or more unique dates. If it does, the second block of the `if` statement will be executed and the script will add a yellow line in the row before the date is changed. Otherwise, it won't do anything.

---

### Solution:

You can execute `color()` as a **standalone** script. I would advice you to save this function in a new `.gs` file and then simply call it within your current script. Namely, put `color()` **anywhere** you want in the code snippet you provided.

```
function color() {
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = sss.getSheetByName("TempDataSet");
  
  const subs = sheet.getRange('E2:E'+sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const usubs = subs.filter((value, index, self)=>self.indexOf(value) === index);
  const dts = sheet.getRange('A2:A'+sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().flat();
  const udts = dts.filter((value, index, self)=>self.indexOf(value) === index);
  
  if(usubs.length>1){
    subs.forEach((s,i)=>{
    if(i>1){
      if(subs[i]!=subs[i-1]){
        sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,5).setBackground('yellow');
      }}});
  }
  else if (udts.length>1){
    dts.forEach((d,i)=>{
    if(i>1){
      if(dts[i]!=dts[i-1]){
        sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,5).setBackground('yellow');
      }}});
  }

  }
```

### Complete Solution:

```
function sendEmails(){  

  
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssID = sss.getId();
  var sheetName = sss.getName(); 
  var sheet = sss.getSheetByName("TempDataSet");
  var sheet1 = sss.insertSheet('TempDataSet_temp');
  sheet.getDataRange().copyTo(sheet1.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  sheet.getDataRange().copyTo(sheet1.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);

  var shID = sheet1.getSheetId().toString();
  sheet1.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() -1, sheet.getLastColumn()).sort({column: 1, ascending: true}); 
  var columns_delete = [7,2]; //[7,5,4,2];
  columns_delete.forEach(col=>sheet1.deleteColumn(col));
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  
 const subs = sheet1.getRange('E2:E'+sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const usubs = subs.filter((value, index, self)=>self.indexOf(value) === index);
  const dts = sheet1.getRange('A2:A'+sheet1.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().flat();
  const udts = dts.filter((value, index, self)=>self.indexOf(value) === index);
  
  if(usubs.length>1){
    subs.forEach((s,i)=>{
    if(i>1){
      if(subs[i]!=subs[i-1]){
        sheet1.getRange(i+1,1,1,5).setBackground('yellow');
      }}});
  }
  else if (udts.length>1){
    dts.forEach((d,i)=>{
    if(i>1){
      if(dts[i]!=dts[i-1]){
        sheet1.getRange(i+1,1,1,5).setBackground('yellow');
      }}});
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var from = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var subject = 'Batch Attendance Record for Your Reference';
  var body = 'Dear Student,'+ '\n\n' + 'Greetings! Please find the batch attendance record attached. Stay safe and blessed.' + '\n\n' + 'Thank you.';
  
  var requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};  
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ ssID + "/export?format=xlsx&id="+ssID+"&gid="+shID;

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);  
  var contents = result.getContent();
  sss.deleteSheet(sss.getSheetByName('TempDataSet_temp'));   
  
  var sheet2 = sss.getSheetByName('StudentList');  
  var data = sheet2.getLastRow();
  var students = [];
  var students = sheet2.getRange(2, 6, data).getValues(); 
  //MailApp.sendEmail(students.toString(), subject ,body, {attachments:[{fileName:sheetName+".xlsx", content:contents, mimeType:"MICROSOFT_EXCEL"}]});
    
  for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++){ // you are looping through rows and selecting the 1st and only column index
    if (students[i][0] !== ''){           
      MailApp.sendEmail(students[i][0].toString(), subject ,body, {attachments:[{fileName:sheetName+".xlsx", content:contents, mimeType:"MICROSOFT_EXCEL"}]}); 
      //MailApp.sendEmail(students[i][0].toString(), subject ,body, {from: from, attachments:[{fileName:"YourAttendaceRecord.xlsx", content:contents, mimeType:"MICROSOFT_EXCEL"}]});
    } 
  }
     
}
```

Comment: it is not working. Please check the Color stripe in the TempDataSet at the attached image of the post (modified), which is not right. And no color stripe is shown in the mail attachment. The code is modified as per your suggestion.

Comment: @TamjidTaha you just changed the picture... The original screenshot had 5 columns and the subject column was in column E. And now there are 6 columns and the subject column moved to column F. This is why it is not working. Give me a couple of minutes and I will change it. But please provide the correct image so there is no confusion like that.

Comment: this is the TempDataSet from where the selected rows of data is fetched. However, we are deleting the column 2 and 7 and then sending the rest 5 columns  dataset as email attachment. Please check the modified code at the post

Comment: I changed this code to const subs = sheet.getRange('F2:F'+sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat(); It is working fine in the TempDataSet but the sheet we are sending as a mail attachment, there is NO color stripe and the TempDataSet stripe need to be cleared after sending emails. You know that the mail attachment sheet is copying from the TempDataSet. So please check the whole code of the post once again.

Comment: @TamjidTaha please try out the complete solution in my answer.